# What should getCheckedRadioButtonId() return after RadioGroup.clearCheck()?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()):

> public void clearCheck ()
>
> Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no radio button in this group is selected and getCheckedRadioButtonId() **returns null**.

But seems like it actually returns `-1`. Also, the line:

```
if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==null)
```

gives the error:

> The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null

Should I count on it returning `-1` after performing `clearCheck()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` (as in the docs) is an `int`. An `int` cannot be `null`, so I think you should rely on `-1`.

Edit: If you're not sure how an Android component works, just check the source code :) For the `RadioGroup`, see for example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RadioGroup.java#RadioGroup.clearCheck%28%29